# In-app billing and in-app-purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have been looking into in-app billing on developer.android.com site but it is useless. I have also installed and looked into their sample app but I still don't understand what to do. because they are using some **un-documented** methods to start service.

I just want a simple and clean implementation like a step by step tutorial. Please help me out.

I still don't understand why they made it too difficult for devlopers?? although Integrating other API are just adding jar and calling some functions e.g. PayPal.

help me please. give link to any good tutorial.

Comment: Android really sucks in-app billing.

Comment: +1 i too agree with u...its very dificult to understand doc and sample provided by them.

Comment: even android apkxpansionfile sample sucks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There definitely is a steep learning curve, but I've found this library to be incredibly useful: https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary

Answer (score 2):

Thats my blogpost as the accepted answer woo!

It is hosted here:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

I've also recently written an overview with a flowchart to try and explain InApp Purchase:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/overview-of-android-in-app-billing-flowchart/

[image]